# How to customize folding in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-editor

I am working on a large single-file C++ project in Visual Studio 2017. I use folding (section collapsing) a lot to make the code readable, but I have to constantly reorganize it because whenever I change something, like add/delete a line of code, some folded sections randomly open. Is there a way to change VS settings to fold code by indentation/another way to fix the issue without splitting the code into multiple files?

I suspect that the folding messes up because of the file size. Making the editor fold sections based on indentation and not on contents would theoretically fix it, but I don't know if that is an option in VS (it is in VS code). I tried disabling IntelliSense and most other fancy features - that did not change anything. The issue only manifests with large file sizes.

Comment: When you say folding, do you mean code section collapsing?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but you can use my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension to make code more readable by showing different parts of the file in the Task Canvas window.